# Markov Chain Question with balls

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am thinking about the following problem and I faced a minor issue:

Consider a bowl that contains initially two blue balls and one yellow ball. At every step you draw a ball randomly. The ball is then put back, and another ball of the same colour is added to the bowl before the next draw. Assume that the experiment is stopped after 2 draws, when the bowl contains 5 balls in total. Upon stopping, the bowl is emptied and the experiment is restarted again with two blue balls and one yellow ball in the bowl. What is the transition matrix that models the content of the bowl over time?

---

It seems pretty straight forward that the state space is {BBY, BBBY, BBYY, BBBBY, BBBYY, BBYYY} where B denotes a blue ball and Y denotes a yellow ball. However, I am confused about the probability for the transitions `BBBBY -> BBY`, `BBBYY -> BBY` and `BBYYY -> BBY`. Should these equal 0, or 1 since this is a repeated experiment? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well I think it depends on what you want to do with that transition matrix. Do you consider restarting the game as part of the process or do you want the process to stay still/idle after the game is over? In the former case the said transition should always happen (probability $1$) since the balls are then rearranged for the start of the game. In the latter case they should be $0$ (you don't want to start the game again) but be careful because for example in the state BBBBY you want to stay in that state (BBBBY -> BBBBY with probability 1) else you don't really have a markov chain.

Comment: @Yuumita Thanks for the answer. Since I was asked for the transition matrix that models the content over time, I assume it would be the former?

Comment: I would personally go for the former case but I don't really have a certain reason for that choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no end to the stochastic process, our transition matrix will model the resetting process. In pre-multiply form it is
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1&1&1\\
2/3&0&0&0&0&0\\
1/3&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&3/4&0&0&0&0\\
0&1/4&1/2&0&0&0\\
0&0&1/2&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
This is the pre-multiply form because the probability of being in a certain state after $n$ steps can be found as
$$\begin{bmatrix}p_{BBY}\\p_{BBBY}\\p_{BBYY}\\p_{BBBBY}\\p_{BBBYY}\\p_{BBYYY}\end{bmatrix}=A^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$